# Contract of ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly

Tags: .net, collections, msdn

I'm writing an array wrapper class that implements `IList<T>`. I’m unsure of what to return for `IList<T>.IsReadOnly` (inherited from `ICollection<T>`), though.

My class disallows insertion and removal. It *does* allow modifying items via the `this[int].set` property.

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cfatk9t.aspx) states that

> A collection that is read-only does not allow the addition, removal, or modification of elements after the collection is created.

For my class, this seems to imply that I have to return `true` but in my eyes this renders the property a <del>bit</del>completely useless: as far as I can see, the use of this method is as follows:

The clients handle an arbitrary `IList` and need to insert an element into it, *if at all possible*. They can do this by just calling `Insert` and catching the resulting `NotSupportedException` – and for various reasons, this may not be desirable. So instead of provoking an exception, the clients can just test the `IsReadOnly` property beforehand.

But the result of this property will be **wrong** because it mixes modifiability of the collection with modifiability of its contents – which are **completely unrelated matters**!

To be sure, there’s the `IList.IsFixedSize` property but this is a separate type (`IList<T>` does *not* extend `IList`). What should I do? Also implement `IList` (I really *don’t* like this alternative)? Do something else?

Comment: Just to add something, with ReadOnlyCollection<T> the contents can be modifiable (if mutable) and still, the "IsReadOnly" property returns true ...

Comment: @bruno - that depends whether by "editing contents" you mean **replacing** the item at a given position (list[n] = item), and **mutating** the item at a given position (list[n].SomeProp = value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something else to consider...

Your collection is an array wrapper and it has some array-like semantics. ie, Items can't be inserted or removed but they can be modified.

Arrays return `false` for `IsReadOnly` and `true` for `IsFixedSize`.

I think I would probably implement `IList` in addition to `IList<T>` and then mimic the array behaviour, so far as `IsReadOnly` and `IsFixedSize` are concerned.

The key word in the [remark from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cfatk9t.aspx) is the "or":

> A collection that is read-only does not allow the addition, removal,
>   **or** modification of elements after the collection is created.

Your collection *does* allow modification, so returning `true` for `IsReadOnly` would be breaking that contract, in my opinion.

Comment: Important: An array does return `false` if you call the public `IsReadOnly` property on it. This public property also is the implementation of `IList.IsReadOnly` on the ***non-generic*** interface `IList`. If the array is a "vector", i.e. it is one-dimensional and starts from index 0 like "ordinary" arrays, the array also implements the generic interface `IList<>`. Then the generic interface `IList<>` inherits an `IsReadOnly` from `ICollection<>`. This `ICollection<>.IsReadOnly` is implemented with a kind of "magical" explicit interface implementation. This implementation returns true!

Comment: An example: `int[] arr = { 2, 4, 6, }; bool x = arr.IsReadOnly; /* false */ bool y = ((IList<int>)arr).IsReadOnly; /* true! */` So if the asker wants to behave like an array, he should return `true` for the implementation of the _generic_ interface.

Answer (score 2):

I think that to meet the contract as defined, you would have to return `true`.

You could (additionally) implement `IBindingList` - this has `AllowNew`, `AllowEdit` and `AllowRemove`. You would return `true` from `AllowEdit`, and `false` from the other two.

Whether your caller checks for this is up to the caller, though. A lot of UI binding code will, though.

added:

Also; you *should* probably implement `IList` if you are implementing `IList<T>`; in particular, `IList` is important for a number of reflection and binding scenarios, where the types aren't known ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks – I (once again) completely forgot about binding (I don’t use it very often). I’ll follow your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the semantics of modification are important. There is a difference between modifying the elements of a collection and modifying the objects contained by the collection. Think of the elements of the actual spaces in the collection. You can't add spaces, remove spaces, or change the object in a certain space. That's the contract that `IsReadOnly` abides by.